# How to set value in BIRT master page from a content page?

Tags: birt

BIRT Reporting:

I want to define a master page in a library and use it as a basis for a number of reports. The master page includes just the company logo, date, page x of y and a space for the report title. The report title will be set by the individual report and may contain query data.

How can a report set data in the master page?

**Clarification**

I want a report (based on a master page) to make a query to fetch data (e.g. report title) and pass that to the master page. e.g. the header contains company logo (fixed) and title (dynamic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was the following.

- define new parameter in the library e.g. MyHeaderText
- give parameter a default value e.g. Staff list
- include the parameter in the report
- overwrite the default value with the required text e.g. Staff - grouped by country

Worked for me.

Comment: I didnt able to get u properly.please elaborate it so that i implement it exactly u want to say. Thankx

Answer (score -1):

just passing the parameters to master-page you can get your values..

Comment: not sure what you mean. Perhaps I didn't make my problem clear. See Clarification